# AppEngine - No Indexes Serving

Tags: java, google-app-engine, indexing, google-cloud-datastore

I have been trying to use Query.setOrdering(xxxx desc) but AppEngine gives ServerError : Unable to process the request.

Admin Console :

```
com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreNeedIndexException: no matching index       found.
The suggested index for this query is:
<datastore-index kind="Chat_messages" ancestor="false" source="manual">
    <property name="FROM_TO" direction="asc"/>
    <property name="TIME" direction="desc"/>
</datastore-index>
```

My code in servlet :

```
Query q=pm.newQuery(Chat_messages.class);
q.setFilter("FROM_TO == email_emailto || FROM_TO == emailto_email");
      q.declareParameters("String email_emailto,String emailto_email");
      q.setRange(0, 50);
      q.setOrdering("TIME desc");
```

Answer (score 0):

With the Python runtime, the process of running the app locally with the dev server generates the index file.

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually getting an error about not having the correct index? The index that you have put in your datastore-index.xml is a single property index. This means that it is automatically built by Datastore and will not show up in your console.

You can see [this page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/indexes#Java_Index_configuration) which describes which queries you can perform without needing to upload any indexes.

Comment: Yeah but When ever i use Query.setOrdering() the app engine server giving error 500:unable to process your request.

Comment: You should provide both the code snippet that is failing and a copy of the stack trace from the logs in the Admin Console.

Comment: In Admin Console :
    Uncaught exception from servlet
    com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreNeedIndexException: no matching index found.
    The suggested index for this query is:
    <datastore-index kind="Chat_messages" ancestor="false" source="manual">
        <property name="FROM_TO" direction="asc"/>
        <property name="TIME" direction="desc"/>
    </datastore-index>

Comment: My Code in Servlet :

    Query q=pm.newQuery(Chat_messages.class);
  q.setFilter("FROM_TO == email_emailto || FROM_TO == emailto_email");
    q.declareParameters("String email_emailto,String emailto_email");
    q.setRange(0, 50);
    q.setOrdering("TIME desc");

Comment: The logs tell you what index to add to your datastore-indexes.xml. This index is different than the one you listed in your question. Try adding the one listed then running `appcfg.sh update_indexes`

Comment: Yeah i already did that and it's in progress...but every time do we have to do that?? like checking logs and adding corresponding indexes.

Comment: Moreover i'm just using index TIME desc why it's suggesting compound index along with FROM_TO asc

Comment: You're not just using the TIME index. Your query has a filter on FROM_TO and an order on TIME. So you need the index: (FROM_TO, TIME). You should be testing your application using the development server (dev_appserver.sh), which when it sees a query will automatically add any indexes that you need to your datastore-indexes.xml. Then, everything will just work when you upload your application.